# Kotlin - Interface with two functions and one of the functions is not working

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, android-arrayadapter

I have an interface with one function and it was working properly. Then I added a second function, which I want to use to send the same array but to a different activity, but in the main activity I'm getting the following error: No value passed for parameter 'PatDischargeBtnDelegate'. Here is my code:

**Interface**

```
interface PatDataCommentDelegate {
    fun patDataCommentBtnClicked(ptdata: PatData)
    fun dischargePatientBtnClicked(ptdata: PatData)
}
```

**Adapter**

```
class PatDataAdapter(val ptdata: ArrayList<PatData>, val patDataBtnDelegate: PatDataCommentDelegate,
                     val patDischargeBtnDelegate: PatDataCommentDelegate) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<PatDataAdapter.ViewHolder>() { 
......


       commentImage?.setOnClickListener {
            patDataBtnDelegate.patDataCommentBtnClicked(ptdata)
        }

        dischargePatImg?.setOnClickListener{
            patDischargeBtnDelegate.dischargePatientBtnClicked(ptdata)
        }
```

**Main Activity**

```
class PatDataActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PatDataCommentDelegate {
....

patDataFromAdapter = PatDataAdapter(ptdatas, this) //I get the error here


 override fun patDataCommentBtnClicked(ptdata: PatData) {
        val commentDataActivity = Intent(this, CommentsActivity::class.java)
        commentDataActivity.putExtra(DOCUMENT_ID, ptdata.documentId)
        commentDataActivity.putExtra(USER_ID, userId)
        commentDataActivity.putExtra(PTNAME, ptdata.ptName)
        commentDataActivity.putExtra(FIN, ptdata.fin)
        commentDataActivity.putExtra(ROOM, ptdata.room)
        commentDataActivity.putExtra(HOSP, ptdata.hosp)
        startActivity(commentDataActivity)
    }

    override fun dischargePatientBtnClicked(ptdata: PatData) {
        val dischargePatientActivity = Intent(this, DischargeActivity::class.java)
        dischargePatientActivity.putExtra(DOCUMENT_ID, ptdata.documentId)
        dischargePatientActivity.putExtra(USER_ID, userId)
        dischargePatientActivity.putExtra(PTNAME, ptdata.ptName)
        dischargePatientActivity.putExtra(FIN, ptdata.fin)
        dischargePatientActivity.putExtra(ROOM, ptdata.room)
        dischargePatientActivity.putExtra(HOSP, ptdata.hosp)
        startActivity(dischargePatientActivity)
    }
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, please any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your adapter constructor takes three arguments but you've only passed two. The last two arguments are both of the type of your interface, so maybe you only meant to have it accept one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here in 3rd argument.

```
class PatDataAdapter(
    val ptdata: ArrayList<PatData>, 
    val patDataBtnDelegate: PatDataCommentDelegate,
    val patDischargeBtnDelegate: PatDataCommentDelegate // you don't need this one.
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PatDataAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
```

This should work:

```
class PatDataAdapter(val ptdata: ArrayList<PatData>, val patDataBtnDelegate: PatDataCommentDelegate) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<PatDataAdapter.ViewHolder>() { 


   commentImage?.setOnClickListener {
        patDataBtnDelegate.patDataCommentBtnClicked(ptdata)
    }

    dischargePatImg?.setOnClickListener{
        patDataBtnDelegate.dischargePatientBtnClicked(ptdata)
    }
```

You only need a reference to interface `PatDataCommentDelegate` itself NOT to each method separately.